# Updating a dependently typed field without updating what it depends on

Tags: record, idris, dependent-type, idris2

I'd like to use record update syntax to update a dependently-typed field without also changing the field it depends on. So I'd like to have Idris 2 evaluate the other field, and realize everything is kosher. Is this doable?

Here's a concrete minimal example:

```
%default total

0 Top : Type
Top = DPair Type (\t => t)

p1 : Top
p1 = MkDPair Bool True

p1' : Top
p1' = { snd $= not } p1
```

Here, the definition of `p1'` doesn't typecheck, because the type of `snd` is `fst`, not `Bool`. But if only Idris would evaluate `p1.fst`, it would all work out.

I am guessing the problem is that this is an application of a general record updater function `{ snd $= not } : Top -> Top` to the argument `p1 : Top`, which of course doesn't quite work. So is there a way to instead *start from `p1`*, and change its field values *in the context of its other field values*?